# How to use a range of keys to index values?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with keys that are iterable (1-10), and I want to find the values for a range of those keys, like from keys 3-8.

```
dictionary = {
1: 2.0,
2: 3.5,
3: 1.1,
4: 4.5,
5: 7.8,
6: 9.8,
7: 7.4,
8: 3.2,
9: 10.0,
10: 11.0}

for key,value in dictionary.items():
if key == 1:
    print(value)
```

This returns `2.0`. If I try a range of values:

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    if key == range(3,8):
        print(value)
```

nothing is returned. Would I have to make an `elif` statement for each value that I want returned or would it make more sense to 'flip' the keys/values and use a range of values to search for keys instead?

Comment: `if key in range(3,8):` not `==`

Comment: Rethink your usage of `dict`. O(n) access kinda defeats the point of using a `dict`. You might as well just use a list of tuples, with  that at least you can use binary search

Comment: Alternatively you could do `if 8 >= key >= 3:`

Comment: To add an explanation to @flakes answer, range function creates a range object as mentioned below.

Comment: @ShimonCohen `range` does *not* create an array. It creates a `range` object

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'll fix the comment.

Comment: In this particular case, you can just do `3 <= key <= 8`, but as others have stated, you may want to re-thing your use of a `dict` here

Comment: @flakes a small reminder that `3 <= key <= 8` is not equivalent to `range(3, 8)`, but `3 <= key < 8` is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `range` of possible keys is smaller than the number of key-value pairs in the dict, it would be cleaner (and faster) to iterate over the possible keys rather than over the entire `dict`.

```
for possible_key in range(3, 8):
    print(dictionary.get(possible_key, 'missing value'))
```